# Using sql to recursively generate values depending on keys and column values

Tags: sql, sqlite, recursion, join

I have a table like this:

| store | item | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| store1 | item1 | 2 |
| store1 | item2 | 3 |

I want to use it to create the following table:

| store | item | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| store1 | item1 | 0 |
| store1 | item1 | 1 |
| store1 | item1 | 2 |
| store1 | item2 | 0 |
| store1 | item2 | 1 |
| store1 | item2 | 2 |
| store1 | item2 | 3 |

I'm aware that I can do `with recursive n(n) as (select 0 n union all select n + 1 from n limit 40)` and then later a cross join if the upper limit was constant `(40)` but in my case, it changes by `(store, item)`. I was wondering if this can be done in SQL or if it is better to figure it out in python. Thanks.

Comment: Tag our question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, it's a sqlite database, thank you for the quick answer, I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE.  The syntax is something like this:

```
with recursive cte(store, item, value, n) as (
      select store, item, value, 0
      from t
      union all
      select store, item, value, n + 1
      from cte
      where n < value
     )
select store, item, n as value
from cte;
```

The exact syntax for recursive CTEs varies, depending on the database.  This appears to be similar to the code you have in your question.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=451b09395dc9f3ec095f0b8b8067ba52) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: This looks very close to what I'm looking for, I think there's an `as (` missing in the first line but even adding that I'm unable to make it work.

Comment: @ATidedHumour . . . I added a fiddle and fixed a couple of typos.